# Weird Routing Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

My routes all act up at times without depending on any condition. Let's say I have a model `pencil`. Sometimes it gives a `Routing Error "Pencils/Pencils/new"`.

What might be causing that? I hope this is a common problem and I can solve it without diving into too much detail.

Edit: Is it possible that the way I render might be causing that? If I am in the same folder(Pencils), sometimes I will write:

```
=render "Pencils/new".
```

Should I be writing:

```
 =render "new"
```

Comment: pencils/new should be your route

Comment: Could you show us a portion of your routes.rb? Running `rake routes` might help shed some light on the issue since it'll show you all the configured routes as well.

Comment: I am also aware that pencils/new should be the correct route. However, for some reasons it tries Pencils/Pencils/new which doesn't exist on my routes. Thus, rake routes wouldn't be of much help as I already know that Pencils/Pencils/new is not a correct route which won't exist on rake routes. Please see my edit for further info.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be writing the template name without the controller name if this view is in the same controller that you are in. For the example above, doing the following is what you need to do:

```
= render 'new'
```

If you are trying to render a view from a different controller, for example, lets say you have a `app/views/shared/errors.html.erb` and you want to render that from `app/views/pencils/index.html.erb` then you can do the following:

```
= render 'shared/errors'
```

Remember to use the lower-cased pluralized form for the controller name if its a different controller (so `pencils` instead of `Pencils`)